# How to create a rule where the from email address is empty

Tags: outlook.com, email-rules

I'd like to create a rule in my Outlook for when I receive emails where the from address is empty. Using Outlook to Block such emails doesn't work because you have to actually put an email address in and if you attempt to block the sender from the tools it'll ask you something along the lines of "Do you want to block emails from the address ? You will no longer..." (there would normally be an email address prior to that question mark(?)). Obviously that doesn't actually achieve anything either.

Is there a way to set up a rule in the Online Outlook client against emails received with no email address in the from?